# Проверка соответвия фото определенному шаблону

Tags: android, java

Добрый день. 
Стоит задача: необходимо проверить, что на фото номерной знак машины, а не что-то иное. Распознавать сам номер нет необходимости.

Вопрос заключается в следующем, есть ли готовые библиотеки, позволяющие это сделать на девайсах с андроидом?

Никогда не сталкивался с темой распознавания изображений.

Answer (score 1):

Если номер на фото соответствует строгому положению (то есть его координаты легко вычислить), то задача относительно проста. Но если это просто фотографии машин, на которых даже человек не всегда может номер определить, то задача усложняется. В этом случае написать функцию, которая дает 100% ответ достаточно сложно, но вот функцию, которая будет давать 70-80% ответ, - можно.

Для андроида есть порт хорошей библиотеки [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) - она бесплатна и доступна.

Также почитайте три части статьи на хабре:

- [Распознавание номеров: от А до 9](http://habrahabr.ru/company/recognitor/blog/221891/)
- [Не соблаговолите ли больше не нарушать, сэр (мэм)?](http://habrahabr.ru/company/recognitor/blog/222539/)
- [Распознавание номеров: от А до 9. Часть 3](http://habrahabr.ru/company/recognitor/blog/223441/).

Там как раз о распознавании номеров и на адроиде. Плюс они пишут, что их наработки взяли в проект OpenCV.

Comment: У меня задача значительно проще. Необходимо подтвердить, что на фото есть какой-то белый прямоугольник(трапеция, т.к. фото будет под углом), и он соответствует определенным критериям

Comment: То есть, если номерной знак заклеен белым скотчем, то это ок? Но даже в этом случае материал выше Вам поможет.

Comment: Да, можно даже сделать фото любого белого прямоугольника заданных размеров.